# In-app price format for Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, in-app-purchase, billing

My app contains in-app products that can be purchased. I use the [billing API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) to retrieve the list of products that can be purchased and their prices.
The retrieved price is a formatted **String** containing both the currency and price, for instance "$2.50".

Now I use as well [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/ecommerce) to track purchases. For sending the price, this API takes a **long** parameter in micros. So I should send (2.50*1000000).

**Is there an API to convert the first price (retrieved from Billing API) to the second one (to send to Analytics API)?**

Of course I could do a simple String parsing conversion myself, but I'm afraid of unexpected cases if I do so. For instance, in some locales, the price would contain "," instead of ".".

**Edit**

A natural solutions would be to use NumberFormat to convert from "$2.50" to 2.50.

```
Double price = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().parse(priceStr).doubleValue();
```

However, the price string format retrieved from Google Play is apparently in the locale of the country where the phone is located, but the NumberFormat would use the locale of the phone which is not necessarily the same...

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not officially documented the Billing API already provides the necessary data in the `getSkuDetails()` response.

Besides the `price` field you also retrieve the following:

`price_currency_code`
The ISO currency code

`price_amount_micros`
The product price in micros (Note: net price)

Comment: Where do you see that? getSkuDetails() returns an object that only has a mPrice member (a String).

Comment: Nevermind: Note that this is not referring to the getSkuDetails() returned by the Inventory object. You'll need to use getSkuDetails() in IabHelper.